# How can I make these labels the same size without using pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I have. I am using bootstrap. I want the labels to be the same size. I don't want to use a fixed width (pixels) because I'm going to be translating this into multiple languages.

An other complication is that this content is added dynamically as HTML text using the jQuery `.html()` function. Most importantly, what event can I handle that would allow me to work on my new code when it actually has a size. If i can do that, I can equalize with jQuery. This seems a bit heavy handed. I would love a CSS solution.

This just feels like the number one weakness with HTML. You cannot do simple these simple things without very heavy solutions.

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <label for="ItemWidth">Width</label>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ItemWidth" name="ItemWidth" type="text" value="0.25" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <label for="ItemHeight">Height</label>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ItemHeight" name="ItemHeight" type="text" value="34.5" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <label for="ItemDepth">Depth</label>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ItemDepth" name="ItemDepth" type="text" value="24" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle that shows things correctly with bootstrap:
http://jsfiddle.net/sbqve4gc/1/

Comment: If you're happy with what bootstrap do, and since it is only CSS, why don't you copy the way they do it? Study their CSS. Otherwise you could use a `<table>` to make sure every column has the same width. Just style it so we don't know it's a table.

Comment: @floribon Bad practice, tables are for representation of tabular data, not for building layouts.

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding what you are asking.  The labels are text strings of variable length. Do you mean you want to make the text appear to all be the same length (meaning font size or letter spacing for each would need to be varied to get to some specific set width)?

Comment: The labels don't line up: http://jsfiddle.net/sbqve4gc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table-row` and `table-cell` demo - http://jsfiddle.net/sbqve4gc/6/

```
.col-md-5 {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
}

.input-group {
    display: table-row;
}

.input-group-addon,
.form-control {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the container div and style it as you wish.

Like this:

```
<div class="input-group-addon YOURCALSSNAME equalize-width">...</div>
```

Then give it CSS:

```
.YOURCALSSNAME {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I NOW HOW CSS WORKS! Read the question.

Comment: It was a typo. Learn how to read a person's question. And you retaliate by down voting me. ::SMH::

Comment: Yes sir, you should be thankful for any answers provided, not a smartass about it. Result: votedown

Comment: I wasn't being a smart ass. And I am thankful for your answers. But too many people don't read the question. Assuming that someone doesn't understand CSS is a little lame. I apologize for shouting, but I'm not going to kiss your ring.